# GRPC C# SSL Server with Windows certificate store

Tags: c#, grpc

Is there any way for GRPC to use Windows Certificate Store (public key cert and private key) when configuring ServerPort with SslServerCredentials? The current API documentation only shows how to pass KeyCertificatePair value.

Martin

Comment: did you ever get an answer?

Comment: Check if this awnser can help you with your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43271833/grpc-c-sharp-server-authentication/59827405#59827405

Comment: @Martin Did you get an answer?