# gRPC C# Server authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, ssl, grpc

I'm attempting to perform server authentication using gRPC however I'm unsure of how to proceed.
My current setup is that I have a server running on one machine and a client on another (both windows machines).
For testing purposes I've generated a certificate authority and a private certificate (from this certificate authority) using the windows makecert.exe.
This generates .cer file.

The documentation for SslServerCredentials does not have any provisions for a .cer file. What would be my KeyCertificatePair in this case ?  The documentation is unclear on this.
http://www.grpc.io/grpc/csharp/html/T_Grpc_Core_SslServerCredentials.htm

Also, I only want the server to authenticate itself, do I need any special provision on the client gRPC call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need both a private key and the cert file.  You can see how the gRPC testing code does it [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/5098508d2d41a116113f7e333c516cd9ef34a943/src/csharp/Grpc.IntegrationTesting/TestCredentials.cs#L83).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you should add this configuration to your appsettings.json

```
},
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Kestrel": {
    "EndpointDefaults": {
      "Protocols": "Http2"
    },
    "EndPoints": {
      "Https": {
        "Url": "https://*:5002",
        "Certificate": {
          "Path": "c:\\test.pfx",
          "Password": "password1234"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "token": "DO6&gkOK5%$fRD#eRt$",
}
```

That certificate can be generated my many ways. IIS or powershell command. In this code is in drive c: just for testing.

Then you should get the token value like this on Program.main :

```
IConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            // Duplicate here any configuration sources you use.
            configurationBuilder.AddJsonFile("AppSettings.json");
            IConfiguration configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();

            string token = configuration["token"];
```

There are people that say that this token shouldn't be on configuration file but for now i don't know where else to put it. You should also investigate that. And tell me if you don't mind :)